# Average num of characters per word in a list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm trying to calculate the average number of characters per word in a list using the following definitions and a helper function `clean_up`.

Definitions:

- A token is a string that you get from calling `split()` on a line of
  a file
- A word is a non-empty token that is not completely made up of punctuation
- A sentence is a sequence of characters that is terminated by, but does not include, the characters `!?.` or the EOF.  A sentence excludes whitespace on both ends and is not an empty string.

```
def clean_up(s):
    """ (str) -> str

    Return a new string based on s in which all letters have been
    converted to lowercase and punctuation characters have been stripped 
    from both ends. Inner punctuation is left untouched. 

    >>> clean_up('Happy Birthday!!!')
    'happy birthday'
    >>> clean_up("-> It's on your left-hand side.")
    " it's on your left-hand side"
    """

    punctuation = """!"',;:.-?)([]<>*#\n\t\r"""
    result = s.lower().strip(punctuation)
    return result
```

My code is:

```
def avg_word_length(text):
    """ (list of str) -> float

    Precondition: text is non-empty. Each str in text ends with \n and
    text contains at least one word.

    Return the average length of all words in text. 

    >>> text = ['James Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul and Mary\n']
    >>> avg_word_length(text):
    5.142857142857143 
    """

    a = ''
    for i in range(len(text)):
        a = a + clean_up(text[i])
        words = a.split()
    for word in words:
        average = sum(len(word) for word in words)/len(words)
    return average
```

I'm getting a value of 6.16666... as my answer.
I'm using Python 3

Comment: Why is that result confusing to you? Do you know the correct answer to be something else?

Comment: The expected output (5.14..) is clearly given in the docstring, which is why the OP is confused.

Comment: You have a definition of a sentence in your question that makes `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111.` legitimate. Where did you get that definition? The fact is you cannot determine where/what a sentence is. Its language, a very subjective thing, that is interpreted and _vague_.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. "def avg_word_length(text)" is the code I wrote. And the the correct answer in the example is 5.1428......@AlexThornton

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. "def avg_word_length(text)" is the code I wrote. And the the correct answer in the example is 5.1428.@DSM

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. "def avg_word_length(text)" is the code I wrote. And the the correct answer in the example is 5.1428.@sln

Answer (score 3):

You have two considerable logical errors in your code.

First, in clean_up, you are removing separators from the start and end of a string, but not consecutive ones within a string. You are also not splitting on the same separators you are stripping; the result is that `"Peter,"` makes it through as a word with one character more than it should.

Secondly, you are concatenating lines after stripping, with `a = a + clean_up(text[i])`. This means you *ensure* that you have too long and few words, since the last word of one line combines with the first word of the next; in this case, you get `"CooperPeter,"` as one word.

Both of these problems are rather evident if you just print `words` before the second loop (which has no reason to be a loop, considering the generator expression within the sum() call).

Personally I'd probably use the `re` module to find words with a single consistent definition (such as `r"\w+"`) and tally their lengths rather than collecting a string with their contents.

Comment: The OP's docstring in cleanup says that inner punctuation is left alone, so they must want the , at the end of Peter...

Comment: but we have not talked about the re module. What is it?@Yann Vernier

Comment: Hm. I did read sloppily, and thought words would be alphabetic only; that did match the number given in the avg_word_length docstring. The docstring value does not match the definitions. The re module is for regular expressions, a language for matching patterns of text.